# Where/what is the endpoint for the specification created by raml in a mule application?

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Project has a raml file which defines the api specification. I can view it when running the application inside AnypointStudio under `http://localhost:8081/console/`. Is this specification available/viewable when the service is deployed to a non-localhost? I can see my api endpoints but wondering where the api specification/documentation. I am looking for something like the default `swagger-ui.html` page for swagger-based api documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The only file inside the application deployable or source project is the RAML file (or files). In the source project it is in the src/main/resources/api/ folder. The file itself is not accessible directly. The console view is generated on the fly at execution time. It is not a physical HTML file inside the application. The default autogenerated application from a RAML in Studio has an HTTP Listener config which listens to all network interfaces (0.0.0.0), not only localhost. If you want something different just change the HTTP Listener configuration or create a new one only for the console, and change the Listener in the console flow.

Alternatively you could add the API Console operation (`<apikit:console config-ref="api-config" />`) to any flow you want. It would be very unusual to have a tool like the API Console (used for testing and documenting) inside the API responses. I believe it is not the right usage for API Console.

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is make this document available as an endpoint in the api. how can i achieve that? can i create a listener and parse-template component with that raml file as the source? Like how would it appear in my http://localhost:8081/console/

Comment: If you just want to share the RAML file then yes, use `<parse-template location="api/api.raml">` to read it from a flow.

Comment: On rereading you last comment it looks like you want to use API Console inside the responses of one you APIs endpoints. I advice against doing that but I updated my answer to include that.

Comment: I thought the raml file is for sharing the api documentation like how we would use swagger. May I know why you advice against using the api console as and api endpoint?

Comment: Let's say you have a REST API that returns JSON documents for its endpoints. Adding the console is returning an interactive HTML UI to document and test the same API, instead of JSON. That's inconsistent and mixes concerns. I don't know of any API implementations that try to do that. Also I believe that is not the expected usage of API Console. It is a tool for testing mostly. That's the reason scaffolded applications have it in a separate flow from the API endpoints.